# Pointer values not passing correctly to overloaded equals operator (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have an overloaded `=` operator which is correctly passing some of the values in the `particle` class, but not other values. I have troubleshooted online, and could not find anything which directly pertained to this problem. My peer who is fairly competent in C++ could not assist, and recommended I post here. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

All the values for `width`, `height`, `wrap`, `particlen` and `array` were passing perfectly. However, the values for `xpos`, `ypos`, `xvel`, and `yvel` were passing with incorrect values. For `xpos` and `ypos`, every 11th element was passing correctly, but all the other elements were equal to zero; I expect none of these values to be zero. In `main`, in the operation immediately proceeding `gen1 = gen0;`, all the dereferenced values for gen0 were correct. I estimate that they were somehow not passed correctly? I will happily post more code/info if required. Again, any insights would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Relevant code:

```
class particle{             
private:
    int* xpos;  
    int* ypos; 
    int* xvel;
    int* yvel;
    int* array;             
    int width;
    int height; 
    int wrap;
    int particlen;
public:
    void operator=(const particle&);
}
```

Relevant parts of overloaded = operator:

```
void particle::operator=(const particle &current){
    int a,b,i,j;
    width = current.width;
    height = current.height;
    wrap = current.wrap;
    particlen = current.particlen;
    array = new int[width*height];
    xpos = new int[particlen];
    ypos = new int[particlen];
    xvel = new int[particlen];
    yvel = new int[particlen];

    for(a=0; a<height; a++){
        for(b=0; b< width; b++){
        this->array[a*width + b] = current.array[a*width + b];
        }
    } 

for(i = 0; i < particlen; i++){
    this->xpos[i] = current.xpos[i];
    this->ypos[i] = current.ypos[i];
    this->xvel[i] = current.xvel[i];
    this->yvel[i] = current.yvel[i];
}
```

Relevant parts of main:

```
int main(){
    particle gen0,gen1;
    gen1 = gen0;
}
```

With Sehe's suggestion, I edited my code. However, I am now getting memory allocation problems with the most simple of commands. The << operator, the first operation called in my main does not allow my array variable to be set equal to an integer in a read in file. I definitely know that the file is readable, as the first output line prints. However, I then get a segmentation fault 11 at `array[i*width + j] = k;`. GDB prints the output: program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x000000010001c4f4 in particle::operator<< (this=0x7fff5fbfcb08, file=0x7fff5fbffa90 "100100") at Before typedef 1 vector.cpp:686
686             array[i*width + j] = k;

I have looked up the correct terminology for the vector library online, and thought my syntax was correct. Any ideas?

Update (9:00 EST 2nd Aug)

I am still having trouble with a NULL pointer. When using gdb to debug, I receive the message:

KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000 0x000000010001d807 in particle::operator<< (this=0x7fff5fbfcb08, file=0x7fff5fbffa90 "5040") at Before typedef 1 vector.cpp:688
688             array[(i*width + j)] = k;

I have little experience with NULL pointers; any suggestions as to why this is happening, and how to fix it? Here is the relevant code (the total code is about 900 lines)

```
class particle{             
private:
    std::vector<int> xpos;  
    std::vector<int> ypos; 
    std::vector<int> xvel; 
    std::vector<int> yvel; 
    std::vector<int> array; 
    int width;      
    int height;     
    int wrap;       
    int particlen; // number of particles read in
public:
    void operator<<(particle);
    void Collision(int, int, particle); 
    void operator>>(char*);
    void operator<<(char*);
};

void particle::operator<<(char* file) // Reads initial input file
{
ifstream in_file;
in_file.open( file);    // open the file
int i,j,k;
}
in_file >> width >> height >> wrap >> particlen;
    for(i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(j=0; j< width; j++){
            in_file >> k;
            array[i*width + j] = k; // This is line 688 which GDB references
        }
    }
}

void particle::operator<<(particle current){
int i,k,j,l;

for(k = 0; k < height*width; k++)
{
    array[k] = 0;
}

k = 0;

for(i=0; i < particlen; i++)
{
    cout << "Current x pos is" << current.xpos[i] << endl;
}

for(i=0; i < particlen; i++)
{

    if(array[ (current.ypos[i]-1)*width + (current.xpos[i] - 1) ] == 0 )
    {
    //cout << "Current X position[" << i << "] is" << current.xpos[i] << endl;
        xpos[i] = current.xpos[i] + (current.xvel[i])*timeinc;
        if(xpos[i] > width) xpos[i] = xpos[i] - width; 
        ypos[i] = current.ypos[i] + (current.yvel[i])*timeinc;
        if(ypos[i] > width) ypos[i] = ypos[i] - height;

    //cout << "Next X position[" << i << "] is" << xpos[i] << endl;
    }

    if(array[ (current.ypos[i]-1)*width + (current.xpos[i] - 1) ] > 1 && current.JC[i] != 1)
    {
        for(l=i+1; l < particlen; l++)
        {
            if(current.xpos[l] == current.xpos[i] && current.ypos[l] == current.ypos[i] && current.JC[l] != 1)
            {
            Collision(i,l,current);
            }
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; i < particlen; i++)
{
    array[ (xpos[i]-1)*width + (ypos[i]-1) ] = 1;
}
Display();}

int main()
{
    char filename[256];
    particle gen0, gen1;
    gen0 << filename;
    gen1 = gen0;
    gen0 << gen1; // Calculates the next state of gen0, based on the values in gen1.
}
```

I know this is long, but I thought that this is the minimal information that I could provide. I thought that perhaps the problem is with the `gen0 << gen1` operator, so I included the method.

Comment: This is a guaranteed memory leak; you're not deleting the original arrays.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I suspect the reverse: I suspect missing copy constructors shallow copying the pointers, but they get freed in one instance.

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>` for your dynamic arrays instead of pointers and `new`. You are just asking for trouble.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry, I am not completely clear how that would help. Could you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: @user2638374 You edit **still** doesn't show any constructor resizing the vectors (or the original arrays, for that matter). I can only assume that you never had that in the first place. Please, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ***minimal but complete***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I hinted in the comment, 99% says you're violating Rule Of Three

- [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Notably, you have the assignment operator, but there's no copy constructor in sight.. This could mean that if copied, the array pointers will end up "illegally" shared. I also *assume* you have a destructor somewhere that deletes those arrays (in one instance), thus invalidating the arrays that were *copied* into another instance.

Fix it by avoiding manual memory management in the first place:

```
#include <vector>

class particle{             
    std::vector<int> xpos;  
    std::vector<int> ypos; 
    std::vector<int> xvel;
    std::vector<int> yvel;
    std::vector<int> array;             
    int width;
    int height; 
    int wrap;
    int particlen; // or use `xpos.size()` e.g.
};

int main()
{
    particle gen0,gen1;
    gen1 = gen0;
}
```

**PS.** You might want to consider using `v.at(i)` instead of `v[i]` whenever you want bounds-checking. This can be considerable help in debugging issues.

Comment: Close: you forgot to delete the manual assignment operator and let the compiler handle it. Rule of Zero!

Comment: Wonderful; thank you for your assistance. I will implement this, and hopefully have it working. If I have any further questions I will let you know.

Comment: You need to implement the default constructor, otherwise your POD members are uninitialized.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for the comment. I did implement a default constructor; just didn't include it in the posted code.

Comment: @sehe I'm still having trouble with memory allocation. For example, whenever I run the code:

    for(i=0; i<height; i++){

        for(j=0; j< width; j++){

            in_file >> k;
            array[i*width + j] = k;

        }
    }

I get a segmentation fault, and GDB gives me KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000. Is this possibly a problem with my compiler?

Comment: @user2638374 Look closely: it is a problem with a null pointer. This can't happen with std::vector. I'm assuming you might be allocating other objects (`particle` itself, maybe) dynamically too and you're invoking a method through a null-pointer? A debugger (or `valgrind`) will come in handy to find the mistake, if you cannot find it through code inspection.

Comment: @sehe GDB tells me that 0x000000010001d807 in particle::operator<< (this=0x7fff5fbfcb08, file=0x7fff5fbffa90 "5040") at Before typedef 1 vector.cpp:688
688             array[(i*width + j)] = k;

This seems to suggest that the problem is with the std::vector?

Comment: @user2638374 Wait, what? You're not making any sense. If you post a minimal sample I'll be glad to look at it. But your mess of a comment doesn't in the least indicate a problem with std::vector.

Comment: @sehe Apologies for the abrupt reply; I have updated my example with a more extensive example of my code.

Comment: @user2638374 See my edit. You haven't adjusted the constructors (which you didn't show in the original code anyways) to resize the vectors. This is the place where you _used to have_ `new ...[particlen]` or (god forbid) `malloc` calls.